# Per-pixel lookup-table

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, opencv, lookup

I was wondering if there was another way to create a per-pixel lookup table in Opencv. What I have now works okay for small resolutions (~4 frames per second) but slow on high resolutions (less than 1 frame per second).

I have read that I can use CUDA but do not know how to use it. If it is the only way can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```
In header file:
    Mat_<Vec<uchar,256>> _GB;
    Mat_<Vec<uchar,256>> _GG;
    Mat_<Vec<uchar,256>> _GR;
…
Mat VideoProcessor::CamCalib(Mat _tempFrame)
{

    Mat_<Vec3b> _frame = _tempFrame;

    for( int i = 0; i < _tempFrame.rows; ++i)
        for( int j = 0; j < _tempFrame.cols; ++j )
        {
            _frame(i,j)[0] = _GB(i,j)[ _frame(i,j)[0] ];
            _frame(i,j)[1] = _GG(i,j)[ _frame(i,j)[1] ];
            _frame(i,j)[2] = _GR(i,j)[ _frame(i,j)[2] ];
        }

    _tempFrame = _frame;

    return _tempFrame;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Having a table of size 256 for each components of each pixel  seems *very costly*! For example, for a 1080p image, you will need to allocate and fill 1.5 Gio of memory for a picture that take just 6 Mio! That being said, note that you can use multi-threading to speed-up this code (eg. using OpenMP).

Comment: I would just use cuda to improve whatever calculation you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jerome, I followed your suggestion. A simple implementation with a 25% increase in performance. For me, since I am doing real-time image capture with software lens correction, memory is not as costly as speed.

So here is what I added:

added in Pro file:
**QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -openmp**

added in CPP file:
**#include "omp.h"**
...
and added just before the "for loop" in method:
**#pragma omp parallel for**

Answer (score 0):

Did some fine tuning.(Added before and after correction image at the end of post)

(1) Assuming lens spherical shape identical in all 4 quadrants, I was able to further increase the frame rate to 9fps for 1920x1080 resolution.

(2) Forced less threads reducing CPU usage from 100% to 80%

(3) Less memory used, lookup table 1/4 of the original size

Note: must be in "release" mode for openMP to function correctly! Again thank you Jerome!

```
Mat VideoProcessor::CamCalib(Mat _tempFrame)
{

    Mat_<Vec3b> _frame = _tempFrame;
    int nrows = _tempFrame.rows-1;
    int ncols = _tempFrame.cols-1;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for( int i = 0; i < _tempFrame.rows/2; ++i)
        for( int j = 0; j < _tempFrame.cols/2; ++j )
        {
            _frame(i,j)[0] = _GB(i,j)[_frame(i,j)[0]];
            _frame(i,j)[1] = _GG(i,j)[_frame(i,j)[1]];
            _frame(i,j)[2] = _GR(i,j)[_frame(i,j)[2]];

            _frame(nrows-i,j)[0] = _GB(i,j)[_frame(nrows-i,j)[0]];
            _frame(nrows-i,j)[1] = _GG(i,j)[_frame(nrows-i,j)[1]];
            _frame(nrows-i,j)[2] = _GR(i,j)[_frame(nrows-i,j)[2]];

            _frame(i,ncols-j)[0] = _GB(i,j)[_frame(i,ncols-j)[0]];
            _frame(i,ncols-j)[1] = _GG(i,j)[_frame(i,ncols-j)[1]];
            _frame(i,ncols-j)[2] = _GR(i,j)[_frame(i,ncols-j)[2]];

            _frame(nrows-i,ncols-j)[0] = _GB(i,j)[_frame(nrows-i,ncols-j)[0]];
            _frame(nrows-i,ncols-j)[1] = _GG(i,j)[_frame(nrows-i,ncols-j)[1]];
            _frame(nrows-i,ncols-j)[2] = _GR(i,j)[_frame(nrows-i,ncols-j)[2]];
        }

    _tempFrame = _frame;

    return _tempFrame;
}
```

[Before and After correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agGdI.jpg)